# How to implement uploading a file using Web API POST which can easily be unit tested

Tags: c#, rest, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

Here are some ideas I have:

1 - Using HttpContext

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostFile()
{
    Save(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0]);
    // ...
}
```

2 - Using Request

```
public async Task<httpResponseMessage> PostFile()
{
     if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
     {
          var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("~/files");
          await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
          // ...
     }
}
```

The first one, the Controller depends on HttpContext which is difficult to mock when unit testing.

The second approach also depends on Request which is relatively easier to mock.

What is the easiest approach to Implement a File Upload using Web API POST action method which can easily be Unit Tested WITHOUT using Mocking frameworks like Moq?

Comment: The ideal way would be to have the file as an input parameter to the method like you could do with an MVC controller using HttpPostedFileBase. I would be interested to know if someone has a solution to this.